# Getting RTP ports of the held call after using consult

Tags: java, voip, cisco, jtapi, cisco-jtapi

I am using call consult in my script:

```
dialoutCall = (CiscoCall) provider.createCall();
TerminalConnection terminalConnection = ctipTerminal.getTerminalConnections()[0];
dialoutCall.consult(terminalConnection,dialToNum);
```

when using consult the other existing call state is changed to hold and the RTP ports are being changed, is it possible to obtain the RTP ports of the call that is on hold state?

The events I get after using consult:

```
Received--> Call/CiscoTermConnSelectChangedEv CTI_1
Received--> Terminal/CiscoRTPInputStoppedEv
Received--> Terminal/CiscoRTPOutputStoppedEv
Received--> Call/CallCtlTermConnHeldEv CTI_1
Received--> Call/ConsultCallActive
Received--> Call/ConnCreatedEv 6050:CampusPT:1
Received--> Call/ConnConnectedEv 6050:CampusPT:1
Received--> Call/CallCtlConnInitiatedEv 6050:CampusPT:1
Received--> Call/TermConnCreatedEv CTI_1
Received--> Call/TermConnActiveEv CTI_1
Received--> Call/CallCtlTermConnTalkingEv CTI_1
Received--> Call/CallCtlConnDialingEv 6050:CampusPT:1
Received--> Call/CallCtlConnEstablishedEv 6050:CampusPT:1
Received--> Call/ConnInProgressEv 6001:CampusPT:1
Received--> Call/CallCtlConnOfferedEv 6001:CampusPT:1
Received--> Call/ConnAlertingEv 6001:CampusPT:1
Received--> Call/CallCtlConnAlertingEv 6001:CampusPT:1
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you should enable and handle the [CiscoRTPInputStartedEv](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/jtapi_dev/14_0_1/cucm_b_cisco-unified-jtapi-developers-guide-14/cucm_b_cisco-unified-jtapi-developers-guide-1251_chapter_0101.html#CUCM_RF_C2425FA7_00), which will indicate the new IP:Port where the hold media will be coming from.

Comment: Hi,
At the beginning of the script I get the RTP ports by the CiscoRTPInputStartedEvent:
handler.ctipRTPOutputStarted.waitTrue();

destHost = ctipRTPOutputStartedEvent.getRTPOutputProperties().getRemoteAddress().getHostAddress();
destPort = ctipRTPOutputStartedEvent.getRTPOutputProperties().getRemotePort();

Comment: But, there is no RTP event I see after using the consult besides the CiscoRTPInputStoppedEv and CiscoRTPOuputStoppedEv.
I edited the thread message and added the full events I'm getting after using the consult method (couldn't put it here because of length msg limit).